# geoip zip code query

Tags: php, mysql, geoip

I have downloaded the csv geoip lite from http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry.
I imported that data into my db as the following tables:

Blocks:
startIP,
endIP,
locid.
Location:
locid,
country,
region,
city,
postalcode,
lat,
long,
met,
areacode.

the code that creates the IPnum is:

```
<? $ip =$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


        list($w, $x, $y, $z) = explode('.', $ip);

        $one = 16777216* $w;
        $two = 65536* $x ;
        $three = 256*$y;

        $ipnum = $one + $two+ $three + $z;
?>
```

then my query is:

```
SELECT postalcode FROM location WHERE locid =(SELECT locid FROM blocks WHERE startIP <= '$ipnum' AND endIP>= '$ipnum' LIMIT 1)
```

for a IP of 69.63.184.142, the ipnum is equal to 1161803918. 
the db does return a query, however, the location is from Australia, and that ip is definitely not in Australia.

those who are familiar with geoip, is it something I am doing wrong as far as formula goes?

Comment: I'm not familiar with geoip, but one thing I once stumbled accross was IP addresses beeing in network order when I expected them to be in host order. This is just a wild guess, but you may want to try it. Just reverse the order of the bytes (that is, $z * 16777216, $y * 65536, ...)

Comment: just tried it, thanks for the suggestion, but still no dice

Comment: Don't know much about GeoIP, but I think you just implemented PHP's built-in [ip2long](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) function the hard way :)

Comment: haha I found that function after I had this script {facepalm}

Comment: One thing -- can you print out the SQL query once you've done your parameter substitution into it? Maybe something's formatting $ipnum as a signed number, or something.

Comment: One thing I noticed in your query: You put single quotes around `$ipnum`. I've I'm not totally wrong, you should remove them as `$ipnum` is a numeric data type.

Comment: Oh, also: you're putting in $ipnum as a string -- enclosing the parameter in single quotes -- is that meant to be the way it works? What type is the column in your database? Because if it's a string in the database, too, you'll be doing alphabetical comparison, rather than numeric. Which means that '1161803918' falls within the range '100' to '200', for example :)

Comment: yeah thanks guys, both the startIP and endIP are int, and I removed the single quotes, still no dice.  I think its something to do with my conversion from the 000.000.000.000 to the ipNum, im not sure what though

Comment: Odd. Certainly looks like you're getting the right number from that conversion. Have you tried a few more IPs? Maybe the database is just broken for that particular IP address. And how many locations do you get back if you just `SELECT locid FROM blocks WHERE...` without the limit?

Comment: Here's their reference for the files they provide. http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one that I use. If it doesn't get a GET var it uses the user's remote address.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['ip'])){
if(preg_match('!^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$!',$_GET['ip'])){
    $ip_address=$_GET['ip'];    
} else {
    print ("invalid ip address");   
}
} else {
$ip_address=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];    
}
$test = file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$ip_address);
$test = unserialize($test);
print "<html><pre>";
print_r ($test);
print "</pre></html>";
?>
```